# XmlDocument in an array like object

Tags: c#, list, microsoft-metro, xmldocument

I googled for hours and didn't find anything.

I'm trying to make a Metro App which is reading from an online XML Service. Getting the XML is not the problem, i'm simply doing it like this ->

`var xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(new Uri(url));`

but now the problem is, how to convert it into a list or something readable like this.

The XML I want to read is really huge and i don't want to go through all nodes with foreach.

A simple Array/List with all nodes and innerText as Value would be awesome.

Is this possible? If yes.. how ?

The structure of my XML is like this ->

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

`<city>`

`...`
  `<credit>`

`...`

`</credit>`

`<forecast>`

`<date value="2013-11-08">`

`...`

`<time value="06:00">`

`...`

`</time>`

`<time value="11:00">`

`...`

`</time>`

`<time value="17:00">`

`...`

`</time>`

`<time value="23:00">`

`...`

`</time>`

`...`

`</date>`

`<date value="2013-11-09">`

`<same content here>`

`</date>`

`<date value="2013-11-09">`

`<same content here>`

`</date>`

`</forecast>`

`</city>`

as you can see... there's a lot of information in the XML and I need nearly everything. In Actionscript I would realize it with a XMLList and make 3 Lists of the date Tags with content, so i can use

`xmllist1.time[0] - xmllist1.time[3]` 
`xmllist2.time[0] - xmllist2.time[3]`
`xmllist3.time[0] - xmllist3.time[3]`

to get my data.

And now i want this XMLList in C#... I hope it's possible...Thx 4 help

Comment: What about nodes that contain nodes? The point is, your Xml may have multiple levels of hierarchy, and there's no single way to flatten it. Which bits of the Xml you are interested in?

Comment: to create whatever datastracture-you-want you have to consider the single nodes of the xml, i don't see any way around that.

If you know the structure of the xml, and it's "plain", you could forget about xml and work with a string: use a regexp to get the parts you want (remember that "general xml can't be parsed by regexp", though)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to parse the list of "city" items from the xml.
I do something similar using XDocument and Linq like this and it should work for you:

```
        XDocument xdoc = <add your code to get xml from url>;
        var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
        var cityList = from query in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "city")
                         select new CityItem
                         {
                             Date = (string)query.Element(ns + "date").Attribute("value").Value,
                             Time = (string)query.Element(ns + "time").Attribute("value").Value
                         };
        public class CityItem
        {
            public string Date {get;set;}
            public string Time {get;set;}
        }
```

Comment: I always get the message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' and can't figure out why...

Comment: Step into the program and make sure the xdoc object is loaded, if it is then step in to see which object is null. I would scale the function down to reading a single value until you get it working.